# Retrieving field values from dynamodb streams using python labmda function

Tags: python-2.7, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb-streams

In the below code the print statement does not return anything.

```
import boto3
import json
import os

# Initiate Firehose client
firehose_client = boto3.client('firehose')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    records = []
    batch   = []
    try :
        for record in event['Records']:
            tweet = {}
            print(record['dynamodb']['Keys']['sentiment']['S'])
            t_stats = '{"sentiment":"%s", "totalnumber":"%n"}\n'\
                             % (record['dynamodb']['Keys']['sentiment']['S'],\
                             record['dynamodb']['totalnumber']['N'])
            tweet["Data"] = t_stats
            records.append(tweet)
        batch.append(records)
        res = firehose_client.put_record_batch(
            DeliveryStreamName = os.environ['firehose_stream_name'],
            Records = batch[0]
        )
        return 'Successfully processed {} records.'.format(len(event['Records']))
    except Exception :
        pass
```

Comment: maybe nothing in `event["Records"]`? `for` loop not getting inside?

Comment: print(record['eventID']) does return the eventID

Comment: is it possible you forgot to call the `lambda_handler` function?

Comment: I have specified lambda_function.lambda_handler in Handler field.